# Return Top 5 Sales by State

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will return the top 5 sales in each State that provides the Debtor Name and the Net Total. I have come up with the following which does do the job, however, I'm sure there is a better way, especially if a new State was added.

I have tried to understand the WHERE IN syntax but not I'm not getting it. I'd appreciate any assistance.

```
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "VI"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "NS"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "sa"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "wa"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "ta"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "ac"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "ql"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC
UNION ALL SELECT  TOP 5 data.DebtorNameShort, data.State, data.NetTotal
FROM data
WHERE State= "nt"
ORDER BY NetTotal DESC;
```

Comment: Any time in programming (including SQL queries) that you are having to do that sort of repeated cut & paste with minor changes between each, stop what you're doing, because you are almost certainly doing it wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the `TOP` syntax I am guessing you are using SQL Server. You should be able to use `row_number()` to return the top 5 values for each state:

```
select DebtorNameShort, State, NetTotal
from
(
  select DebtorNameShort, State, NetTotal,
    row_number() over(partition by state order by NetTotal desc) seq
  from data 
) d
where seq <= 5
```

[`row_number()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is a windowing function that will allow to to create a sequential value for each item in a partition - for your example you will partition the data by the `state`.  As long as you order the `NetTotal` in descending order then you can filter the final result to only return those rows will a row number of 1-5.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work;

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT DebtorNameShort, State, NetTotal,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY NetTotal DESC) rn
   FROM data
)
SELECT DebtorNameShort, State, NetTotal
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Here I'm using a common table expression to get the row number of each row ordered by NetTotal descending, per state. That row number can then easily be used in a query to filter out the top 5 rows per state.

Comment: hi bluefeet & Joachim,